# Internal Jquery to external

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Could someone please explain to me how to change this internal js to external. If there is something in the file that is isn't show it is another document but I do need all the ID's and Class's that are mentioned

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title><?php echo $pageTitle; ?></title>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">

    <!-- CSS link -->
    <link href="Content/css/tlm-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <h1><a href="tlm-home.php" title="TLM Project Management"><img src="Content/images/coloured-logo.svg" alt="TLM logo">TLM Project Management</a></h1>
        <nav id="top-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="tlm-register.php" title="Register">Register</a></li>
                <li><a href="tlm-login.php" title="Login">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <nav id="sidebar">

            <a href="#" class="nav-toggle-btn"></a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="tlm-home.php" title="Home">Home</a>
                <li><a href="tlm-manage-projects.php" title="Manage Project">Add&nbsp;Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="tlm-projects.php" title="All Projects">All&nbsp;Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Users">All Users</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <section class="content">
        </section>
        </main>
    <footer>
        <section id="copy">
            <p>&copy; 2016 | TLM Content Management System | Tara McNeil</p>
        </section>
    </footer>

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="Scripts/tlm-scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        (function() {

            var bodyEl = $('body'),
                navToggleBtn = bodyEl.find('.nav-toggle-btn');

            navToggleBtn.on('click', function(e) {
                bodyEl.toggleClass('active-nav');
                e.preventDefault();
            });

        })();

   </script>
```

Comment: do you mean copy the JS inside the `script` tag here to the external JS file named `tlm-scripts.js` ? is that what you mean?

Comment: yea thats what i meant sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you want but I would replace the contents of your `script` tag with this function call in your HTML

```
<script>
    initToggle();
</script>
```

Then on your `tlm-scripts.js` file, I would define the function, something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /// here goes your existing code on that file
    /// if they are related to jquery
    //...
    //...

    // define function that does the toggle
    var initToggle = function(){
        var bodyEl = $('body'),
            navToggleBtn = bodyEl.find('.nav-toggle-btn');

        navToggleBtn.on('click', function(e) {
            bodyEl.toggleClass('active-nav');
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    };
});
```

Lastly, include your custom JS file ***after*** your Jquery files

**UPDATE**

If you do not want JS on your HTML page, then change the function declaration to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /// here goes your existing code on that file
    /// if they are related to jquery
    //...
    //...

    // define function that does the toggle
    var initToggle = function(){
        var bodyEl = $('body'),
            navToggleBtn = bodyEl.find('.nav-toggle-btn');

        navToggleBtn.on('click', function(e) {
            bodyEl.toggleClass('active-nav');
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    };

    // invoke function here, not in the HTML
    initToggle();
});
```

Comment: I tried this is doesn't work I not that great with js and jquery. I am working on a side nav bar that when you click the <a class=".nav-toggle-btn"></a> the side nav will move on and off the page but I dont want any internal script. But I don't know how to access a class and id with jquery.

Comment: @TaraMcNeil To access a class, use this selector `$('.classname')` <- notice the dot in front of the class name.  Similarly, to access an id use `$('#idname')` <- notice the `#` in front of the id.  Maybe look into the Jquery API for all details about it:  https://api.jquery.com/

Comment: @TaraMcNeil any reason you do not want any internal scripts? - you do not have to have it (updated my answer) but there are pros/cons of having some JS scripts in your page

Comment: personal preference I guess. I prefer to keep js, css, and html separate it was the way I was taught. Thanks for your help I will try that.